# How do I get current project directory inside a git hook?

Tags: git, flutter, githooks

I have a pre-commit hook running in my flutter project directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd D: || exit
cd AndroidProjects/json_test/ || exit

flutter pub run
```

It is as follows. I am running the git command (git commit) in local terminal at project directory, so `D:AndroidProjects/json_test/> git commit`  And then the hook is executed.

Is there a way I get project path in which I am running git commit, right to the hook, without hardcoding it inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) says:

> Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either
> `$GIT_DIR` in a bare repository or the root of the working tree in a
> non-bare repository.

(Read the linked documentation for exceptions.)

You may therefore inspect the current working directory to find the top level of the working tree, assuming a non-bare repository.